# How to combine COUNTIFS with INDIRECT?

Tags: excel

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
method  method_year season_year station sample  Macoma_length
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016     1       1       20
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016     1       2       17,5
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016     1       2       12
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016     1       2       19
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016     1       3       5
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016     1       3       2
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016     1       3       2
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016     1       4       18
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016     1       4       7,5
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016     1       4       3
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016     1       4       2
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016     1       5       8,5
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016     2       1       15
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016     2       1       13
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016     2       1       3
```

The data covers two methods (GEMAX and grab) in two different seasons (autumn 2016 and summer 2017) on 6 different stations (1-6) with 5 samples from each (1-5), with different numbers of Macoma found on each station, telling me the length of each Macoma measured.

I now need to change it into this kind of format:

```
method  method_year season_year station sample  1,0  1,5   2,0  2,5  3,0
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016 1       1                           
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016 1       2                           
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016 1       3                       
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016 1       4                           
GEMAX   GE_2016     autumn 2016 1       5
```

This would then tell me how many Macoma of each size class there are in one sample.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a formula I could use so that I could do this easily. So far I've come across the functions COUNTIF and INDIRECT, which would probably work, but I can't get the formula right. The solution I'm aiming for is something like

=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("$F2; "&O6))

but that gives me an error and I can't figure out what I'm supposed to be doing.

So, what I need to have is something like

=COUNTIF([a vector of Macoma_lengths in the sample being calculated], "[the category specified at the top of the column (e.g. 1,0)])

but I can't figure out how to make INDIRECT do what I want it to do.

I have two questions:

1) How to write this code right?

2) Can I use some other function (COUNTIFS?) to have excel select the right method, season_year and station for me so that I don't have to manually select the range for each sample within station within season_year within method?

Comment: Would a pivot table be easier here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use COUNTIFS()

```
=COUNTIFS($L:$L,$A2,$M:$M,$B2,$N:$N,$C2,$O:$O,$D2,$P:$P,$E2,$Q:$Q,F$1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise the function was that simple to use. Now I feel stupid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to steal Tim Williams idea and go with the pivot table.
Here's the idea:

- For the main table, add a column (hate to do this, but it makes it easy) called "Macoma_Class"
- Enter a formula to indicate the class - something like `=MROUND("Macoma_length"/x,.5)` or similar to get the class values
- Create the pivot table with:

  - Row value(s): Station, Sample
  - Column value: Macoma_Class
  - Values: Count of Macoma_Class
- Add Year and Season as filters so you can sort as desired.
  Result is close and can be better if we have more "class" detail...
  [image]

Comment: Well, the table only has values from 1 - 22, at intervals of 0.5 (1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5 etc. all the way to 22.0), so it can't have values like 2.7, for example. Does it still require me to make the "Macoma_Class" column, though?

Comment: @Snowfaerie - I figured, but am not sure how you figure out the "Macoma_Class" so I put in a simple formula. Do you have a formula for the class, or do you assign it based on non-formula criteria? Either way, once you have the class input, then you will have a static set of values and you will not need to group the classes.

Answer (score 0):

I did not see a need to use indirect cell references to get the included picture.

Assuming that you know which stations and samples you are capturing, you could simply set up a formula to do counts based on the row and column values using COUNTIFS.

I put the rearranged data in the same page starting in row 20.  The formula in Cell G20 is:

```
=COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$16,$D20,$E$2:$E$16,$E20,$F$2:$F$16,G$19)
```

and this formula should be copied across and down the rows where you want the counts to go.[image: What the table looks like]